# Trying to port a .NET 4.0 project to .NET Standard 1.4 with ConfigurationSection

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I've got a .NET 4.0 project which I'm trying to convert to .NET Standard 1.3 or 1.4.

In my 4.0 project it currently has some `ConfigurationSection` code which I'm not sure how to port.

I understand with .NET **Core** that things have changed with config files and stuff, but this is a .NET **Standard** class library so I'm not sure how this works/what this means.

What is the recommended thing to do?

Is it literally use a specific NuGet package and I'm good? Does this mean I need to change some code so it's more xplat happy, though?

Comment: `System.Configuration` was the way to read configuration files and then you can access the settings at runtime. So for .NET Standard projects, you should only define and use the "settings", and leave the tasks of reading configuration files to those platform specific projects that can use `System.Configuration` or whatever that platform supports. Definitely you need to change your code.